# Why do I need to mention name attribute or ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}" while using ngModel?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am working on an Angular Form. I have a domain model with some properties. I am binding them by using `ngModel`.

During this, if I don't use `name` attribute then I get the below error.

> ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as
>   'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Example 1:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
```

Example 2:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Why do I need to mention `name` attribute or `ngModelOptions` while I am binding domain model in two-way binding?

When I applied `ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}"` to all of my fields, then my form's valid = true in all cases whether the control (*with property `required`*) has value or not.

My form is:

```
<form #detailForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(detailForm)" id="ngForm">
</form>
```

While my submit button is outside the form:

```
<input type="button" form="ngForm" class='Button' value="Save" (click)="detailForm.ngSubmit.emit()" [disabled]="!detailForm.form.valid" />
```

Comment: I guess you are not using a template driven from that's why we need to write it is a `standalone`. If you are using a template driven form then `standalone` is not required.

Comment: <form #detailForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(detailForm)" id="ngForm"> and my submit button is a normal button outside the form.

Comment: Behind a form, there is a FormGroup containing FormControls, identified by a name. Setting the name attribute of the input allows defining the name of the form control. Without name, Angular can't register the form control into the form group.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Form is just a set of key/value pairs. Name is the key which is used to identify/get/set the value of this control, so you need to specify the name of each control. When you set `ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}"` you tell angular **to not include** this input into the form. That's why your form is always valid. It is actually empty.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#options

Comment: Ok, now if I set name for each control, then I have two objects of same properties. 1 is my domain object while another is  object return by form.value. Is it correct to do so?

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand what do you mean by "same properties". You cant have two controls with the same name, no other restrictions.

Comment: I mean to say that if I have a json object (Person) received from API and I bind that json object (Person) to my form using (for example) [(ngModel)]="Person.personName" and also add a name attribute name="personName". Now I have a json object and another object returned by form.value.

Comment: I'm still not sure what are you asking.
1. You binding not the object `Person` but it's property `personName`. 2. `form.value` will contain new object with the structure of the form you defined in template. 1 and 2 is not the same objects.

Comment: Sorry, I could not explain well. In my case Person Object has properties which need to bind with the form controls. Suppose 10 input controls and 10 properties in Person Object. Now, If I bind these 10 properties to the form using ngModel, name attribute, then form.value return an object with 10 properties. In this way, I have a Person Object with 10 Properties and form.value with 10 Properties.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem with a dynamic form. I must add new row into my form (which include inputs) and when I add new data to my form old fields values was clean.

I fix this with:

```
..*ngFor="let item in formArr; let i = index"...
    ..name="myInput-{{i}}" #myInput{{i}}="ngModel"..
```