# Dynamically binding name property in ngForm?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

need to bind the name property dynamically using ngFor

```
<tr *ngFor="let subject of subjectSet1; let i = index">
              <td>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [name]="i" ngModel checked />
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="text-left">
                <input type="text" [name]="i" [value]="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ngModel disabled/>
              </td>
  </tr>
```

But that gives me this error message

```
ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
  control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

  Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
  Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to mention name attribute or ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}" while using ngModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108719/why-do-i-need-to-mention-name-attribute-or-ngmodeloptions-standalone-true-w)

Comment: He mention the class attribute, so it should be enough. I am trying to reproduce the error in stackblitz but (1st)  I get an error that `number can't assign to string` cause `i` is a number and is assigne to `name` attribute that requires a string. And (2nd) If i fix this, it works as expected...

Comment: no , I need to assign the value i to name property

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways that you can bind `name` attribute to a value.

1. `[name]="i"` like you did.
2. `[attr.name]="i"` with that way you can bind any attribute of any element to your value.
3. `name="{{i}}"`

The error `ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.` is very clear and it means that if a name attribute is not present inside a form control you should use explicit `[ngModelOptions]="standalone"` so angular can exclude this control from form validation.